# Cause of a stack overflow in this method (floating-point math)

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I occasionally get a stackoverflow exception in this method.

```
double norm_cdf(const double x) {
    double k = 1.0/(1.0 + 0.2316419*x);
    double k_sum = k*(0.319381530 + k*(-0.356563782 + k*(1.781477937 + k*(-1.821255978 + 1.330274429*k))));

    if (x >= 0.0) {
        return (1.0 - (1.0/(pow(2*M_PI,0.5)))*exp(-0.5*x*x) * k_sum);
    } else {
        return 1.0 - norm_cdf(-x);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on why i might be getting it ? Any steps I can take to rectify the error ?

Comment: I haven't delved deep into your logic yet, but what I suspect is that `1.0 - norm_cdf(-x)` is producing a negative result for some reason occasionally, which could possibly lead to unbounded recursion

Comment: To confirm, do you have some sample inputs that are triggering the SO exception?

Comment: There really isn't a need for recursion on this problem...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Likely this method is just the straw that breaks the camel's back. This function will only call itself at most once, so it's not the problem. **(Edit: Or it's the NAN issue others point to, which *will* result in infinite recursion.)**

You can easily make the function not recursive anyway, which might be a simpler option.

```
double norm_cdf(double x) {
    bool negative = x < 0;
    x = abs(x);
    double k = 1.0/(1.0 + 0.2316419*x);
    double k_sum = k*(0.319381530 + k*(-0.356563782 + k*(1.781477937 + k*(-1.821255978 + 1.330274429*k))));

    double result = (1.0/(pow(2*M_PI,0.5)))*exp(-0.5*x*x) * k_sum;
    if (!negative)
        result = 1.0 - result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nope, see Dave's answer - `NAN` will cause infinite recursion.

Comment: Or...NAN if that's actually what's happening.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the obvious way of not requiring recursion.

Comment: @Fiktik actually no, he's optimised out a (1-(1-answer))

Comment: @Dave IC, didn't see that

Comment: This is not the same function. What if x = -4.317008278726776? Then in the original case, k = divide by 0 error, but in this case, k = 0.5.

Comment: @Chloe he converts `x` to be positive before that line. Actually looking at it now, that's an error, because he marked `x` as `const` in the parameters. Since that's the only place `x` is used (except for `x*x` but obviously the sign doesn't matter there), he would be better off just putting the `abs` in the equation. That also means that the `negative` variable isn't needed. So there's room for a lot of improvement!

Comment: @Chloe actually I misunderstood your problem with it. The original code has a divide by zero in that case, but then doesn't actually use it.

Comment: another exercise in micro-optimisation is that a multiply can be removed by calculating `k` as `k = 4.317008278726777 / (4.317008278726777 + fabs( x ))`

Comment: @Dave I think you're misunderstanding the goal of this answer. The goal was not to perform every kind of microoptimization for the OP. The goal was to tell him "You can easily rewrite your function so that it's not recursive." I'm not doing all his work for him. :)

Comment: @TimothyShields no I get that. I just got started with optimising it and couldn't stop myself!

Comment: @Chloe I did fix the `const` on the parameter that shouldn't have been there, but otherwise I think this function behaves identically to the OP's, just without recursion. And that's what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 24):

Your problem is when `x` is Not a Number. `NAN >= 0.0` is false, `-NAN >= 0.0` is also false.

You could check against NAN specially, as others have suggested, but I would suggest simplifying things:

```
static double norm_cdf_positive(const double x) {
    double k = 1.0/(1.0 + 0.2316419*x);
    double k_sum = k*(0.319381530 + k*(-0.356563782 + k*(1.781477937 + k*(-1.821255978 + 1.330274429*k))));

    return (1.0 - (1.0/(pow(2*M_PI,0.5)))*exp(-0.5*x*x) * k_sum);
}

double norm_cdf(const double x) {
    if (x >= 0.0) {
        return norm_cdf_positive(x);
    } else {
        return 1.0 - norm_cdf_positive(-x);
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that compilers can make smarter assumptions about its behaviour. Note that I've marked the "internal" function static (which will limit its scope to the current compilation unit). You could also use unnamed namespaces. (edit: actually Timothy Shields has a simpler way of removing the recursion, which keeps everything in one function)

Comment: could u tell me what is NAN ?

Comment: Not A Number. For example `0.0/0.0` or `sqrt(-1.0)` (unless you're using complex numbers). It comes up every now and again in places where you wouldn't expect it, unless you've put effort into avoiding it.

Comment: NAN is Not-A-Number.  It is the result of invalid calculations (but not as simple as Divide-by-zero errors)

Comment: @abelenky: Well, then divide-by-zero is clearly not an "error" :-)

Comment: Hm, I'd say that "optimization" is a bit premature. The simple solution Timothy suggested seems just as good, and is most likely going to be optimizable with a conditional move.

Comment: @KerrekSB I didn't claim this was more optimal. I hadn't actually seen his answer when I suggested that (I just wanted to move away from the answers which were suggesting special checks for NAN). I've updated my answer to point to Timothy's suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

When `x` is `NaN`, the recursion will never terminate. Add a check: Either [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) in C++11, or the lazy `x != x`, or document-and-blame-user. If you choose to handle `NaN`, propagating it might be a sensible choice.

Comment: Could u tell me how x!=x going to help

Comment: @Rajeshwar: It's a dirty test for whether a floating point number is `NaN`. `NaN` is the only floating point value that is not equal to itself.

Comment: Hmm that sounds interesting have to look that up